# where are the src/js and build/js directories?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

A noob question. I am using node v4.2.1 and gulp 3.9.0 on windows 7 and I am using a [tutorial](http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-the-task-runner-gulp)

to learn the task runner gulp. I am trying the task with the concatenation but I cannot find the src/js and build/js directories. Is it happen because of the version's difference?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use any file structure of your choice and you can simply create the directories yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src/js` is your own source directory, which can be anything you like, `src/js` is just common by convention.

Similarly `build/js` is a folder that the files you run through the task end up in.

So your project should look similar to this:

```
gulpfile.js
|
|-- src
|    | index.html
|    |
|    |-- js/
|    |    |
|    |    | foo.js
|    |    | bar.js
etc etc   etc
```

and after running the task you'll end up with

```
gulpfile.js
|
|-- src
|    | index.html
|    |
|    |-- js/
|    |    |
|    |    | foo.js
|    |    | bar.js
|    etc
|
|-- build
|    | index.html
|    |
|    |-- js/
|    |    |
|    |    | foo.js
|    |    | bar.js
etc  etc  etc
```